# Как можно расширить длину битовой маски?

Tags: алгоритм, битовые-операции

Например, у меня есть список прав которые закодированы в битовую маску:

```
const int R0 = 1 << 0;
const int R1 = 1 << 1;
const int R2 = 1 << 2;
...
const int R31 = 1 << 31;
```

Как видно, 32 - это максимальное количество прав которые можно закодировать (при условии, что INT может занимать не более 32бита).
Но что, если, мне понадобится добавить еще права - как тогда расширить маску?

Comment: Использовать второй DWORD для хранения еще 32 полей?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, Нет. Для c++ можно, а если у меня php?

Comment: Ну если вы не можете использовать еще одну переменную - никак нельзя.

Comment: А какая разница, какой язык. делаете массив из нужного кол-ва int. номер бита в маске делите на 32 - получаете номер int в массиве, потом из этого int берете бит с номером бита & 31 (он же остаток от деления на 32)

Answer (score 4):

Для начала взять `unsigned int` :)

Потом - если есть более широкий `unsigned long` или `unsigned long long`.

Можно, в конце концов, просто взять массив `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас PHP, то все еще проще. Тут битовые операции работают со строками и можно оперировать масками любой длины (главное чтобы оперативки хватило). Получится несколько сложнее с масками, но вполне наглядно.

*Определение масок:*

```
define('R0', "\x01");
define('R1', "\x02");
define('R2', "\x04");
define('R3', "\x08");
// ...
define('R7', "\x80");
// ...
define('R22', "\x00\x00\x40");
define('R23', "\x00\x00\x80");
// ...
define('R78', "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x40");
define('R79', "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80");
define('R80', "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80");
// ...
```

*Комбинация масок:*

```
$flags = R1 | R23 | R78;
```

*Проверка маски (немного извращений 18+):*

```
if (($flags & R23) === R78) {
    // будет выполнено
}
if (($flags & R79) === R79) {
    // НЕ будет выполнено
}
```

Обратите внимание - "старший байт" находится в конце строки.